# Centering multiple items in flexbox not working as expected

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to vertically content within a div with flexbox, so that it always remains centered.

However it is not working as expected. Interested to see where I'm going wrong.

Just to confirm, the 'left div' should display the contents in regular vertical order, not horizontally as is currently happening.

```css
section {
  display:flex; 
}

div {
  padding:12px;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.left {background:#bada55}
.right {background:red}
```

```html
<section>
            <div class="left">
                <h2>Very long title</h2>
                <p>Caption goes here</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque at magni est facilis error! Perspiciatis ab tempore qui mollitia, nihil itaque praesentium deleniti hic asperiores soluta, rem natus. Quidem, necessitatibus?</p>
            
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa distinctio, labore, quod ex blanditiis totam esse eligendi consequatur inventore reprehenderit temporibus architecto molestias ratione, ullam deserunt tempora nesciunt corrupti! Tempora!</p>
            </div>
            
        </section>
```

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/juicypixels/pen/bGwQrOG)

Comment: use column in left and then justify-content:center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex-direction` on `.left` to make it center vertically:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  padding: 12px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background: #bada55;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right {
  background: red;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">
    <h2>Very long title</h2>
    <p>Caption goes here</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque at magni est facilis error! Perspiciatis ab tempore qui mollitia, nihil itaque praesentium deleniti hic asperiores soluta, rem natus. Quidem, necessitatibus?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa distinctio, labore, quod ex blanditiis totam esse eligendi consequatur inventore reprehenderit temporibus architecto molestias ratione, ullam deserunt tempora nesciunt corrupti! Tempora!</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Sorry I was just about to edit my original post. The trouble with flex-direction:column (and justify content) is that it centers each element. I want the relationship between the elements to stay the same, I just want to center the group. Does that make sense? I'd also like to avoid adding another div just to do this

Comment: Couldn't you just use `align-items: center` on `.right` instead?

Comment: No that doesn't work as it doesn't vertically center the .left contents. To make it clearer, this is visually the result i'm looking for https://codepen.io/juicypixels/pen/oNzQGNa

Answer (score 0):

EDIT based on your comment, I believe this works:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
}

div {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 12px;
}

div.right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="left">
    <h2>Very long title</h2>
    <p>Caption goes here</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque at magni est facilis error! Perspiciatis ab tempore qui mollitia, nihil itaque praesentium deleniti hic asperiores soluta, rem natus. Quidem, necessitatibus?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa distinctio, labore, quod ex blanditiis totam esse eligendi consequatur inventore reprehenderit temporibus architecto molestias ratione, ullam deserunt tempora nesciunt corrupti! Tempora!</p>
  </div>      
</section>
```

Comment: No that doesn't work as it doesn't vertically center the .left contents. To make it clearer, this is visually the result i'm looking for https://codepen.io/juicypixels/pen/oNzQGNa